# Разница в отображении страниц на печать, на различных страницах хотя стили одни

Tags: javascript, html, css, print

Уже битый день долблюсь, не могу понять в чем проблема.На "главной" и на странице "цены" при нажатии на кнопку печать, выходит разный результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итог на странице главная:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

страница цены:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@media print
```

{

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm !important;
}

span.print-heading
{
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    font-size: 28px !important;
    color: #82b440 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    page-break-before: always !important;
    z-index: 999 !important;

}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl
    {
    position: relative !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .material_wrapper .m_legend h3
    {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 24px !important;
    }


.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .m_wrapper
{
position: relative !important;
page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}

.material_wrapper{
    top: 5px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    /*page-break-inside: avoid;*/
    page-break-before: always !important;
    page-break-after: always !important;
    /*min-height: 700px;*/
    z-index: 999 !important;
}

.material_wrapper:first-child{
    position: relative !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    top: -70px !important;
    /*page-break-inside: auto;*/
    page-break-before: auto !important;
    page-break-after: auto !important;
}

.tg-main-section.pricing,
.materials_wrapper .m_tbl>div
    {
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    }

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl>div,
.tg-main-section.pricing
{
position: relative !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.tg-main-section.services,
.tg-main-section-2,
.tg-main-section-3,
.lifestyle-area,
.tg-main-section-products,
.tg-main-section.materials,
#footer,
.tg-home-slider,
#header,
.tg-banner,
tg-breadcrumb,
.materials_wrapper .m_navi a.print_btn,
#languages,
.preloader-bg,
top-alert,
modal-alert-bg,
.materials_wrapper .m_navi .m_btns button,
.materials_wrapper .m_navi .m_btns,
.tg-section-head,
.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .m_image,
parallax-mirror,
img
{
    display: none !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .m_wrapper .m_price_info
{
position: relative !important;
min-width: 150px !important;
text-align: right !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_legend
{
position: relative !important;
margin-top: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 20px !important;
display: flex !important;
align-items: center !important;
justify-content: space-between !important;
align-items: center !important;
width: 100% !important;
left: 0 !important;
right: 0 !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_legend .row div[data-mcol="1"]
{
width: auto !important;
height: 100% !important;
min-width: 150px !important;
z-index: 999 !important;
position: relative !important;
display: flex !important;
justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_legend h3
    {
    position: relative !important;
    color: #82b440 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    /*page-break-before: always !important;*/
    /*page-break-after: auto !important;*/
    }

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .material_wrapper .m_legend h3 + .row
{
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_navi .m_btns button,
.materials_wrapper .m_navi .m_btns
{
display: block !important;
position: absolute !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_navi
{
position: relative !important;
border-bottom: none !important;
}

*
{
background-color: #fff !important;
position: relative !important;
}

body
{
position: relative !important;
bottom: 0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
left: -5px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
max-height: 100% !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
height: auto!important;
float: none!important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .material_wrapper:nth-child(1)>.m_legend
{
    border-bottom:4px solid #fff !important;
    position: relative !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .material_wrapper>.m_legend
{
    position: relative !important;
    border-bottom:4px solid #82b440 !important;
    bottom: -17px !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl>div
{
    position: relative !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    left: -2px !important;
    page-break-before: auto !important;
    page-break-after: auto !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}


.materials_wrapper .material_wrapper .row
{
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .m_wrapper .m_main_info h4
{
    position: relative !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: #82b440 !important;
}

.materials_wrapper .m_tbl .m_wrapper
{
    position: relative !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

}

сам сайт https://basemetal.multiweb.ee/price

Comment: А вы можете уверены, что за печать отвечает один и тот же метод? Параметры совпадают? И видеть бы пример кода в снипете...

Comment: @doox911 Да метод один и тот же. Вообще это же стандартная функция от js  window.print(); А то что уже на печать я стилями и редачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в своей невнимательности. Исправлено теперь работает как надо. На странице цены был элемент .parallax-mirror, который я все время пропускал. при добавлении его в правило в css @print все стало как надо.

Comment: Подробнее давайте, раз уж начали